# What is XMPassport?

Tags: android-11, android-one

I discovered this on the Android 11 settings:

[image: Android 11 Android One setting]

I don't know what it means and what it is for. Kinda like a credential manager for certs.

How can it be used?

UPDATE: (approx) image translation to english:

```
 XMPassport
   Installed for VPN and
   apps

     Credentials
     XMPassport
     Installed for VPN and apps
     Record contents:
     one user key
     one user certificate

     DELETE DONE
```

Comment: Most likely the device is from Xiaomi: On xda there is a log showing the class name  `com.xiaomi.accountsdk.account.XMPassport`.

Comment: yes, this is Xiaomi.